# What is the StringComparison method of string.IndexOf(string)?

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I know `string.IndexOf("some string")` is performing a case-sensitive and culture-sensitive comparison.

[MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_).

> [...] This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) search using the current culture. The search begins at the first character position of this instance and continues until the last character position. [...]

However, does that mean it is equivalent to using `string.IndexOf("some string", StringComparison.CurrentCulture)`?

I'd like to know which precise member of `StringComparison` is being used or is equivalent to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the .NET Framework (and core) source is available, so here is the relevant code : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,2307

> ```
> public int IndexOf(String value) {
>             return IndexOf(value, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
>         }
> ```

Comment: Thank both of you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here's the source code: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.Searching.cs,cf9e6bfe83442551,references

```
public int IndexOf(string value)
{
    return IndexOf(value, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Comment: Thank both of you! :)